# Rewrite rule with parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

First of all my web is on Joomla 3.0.

I want to rewrite urls with parameters to another urls better to read and more friendly by the .htaccess archive.

I read the documentation several times but hasn't become clear to me.
I have a url like this:

https://MYWEB.com/buy?Type=event&Step=place&ID=1695

I need something like this:

https://MYWEB.com/buy/event/place/1695

Is it posible to do this?

I tried a lot of combinations, this is my last attempt:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  


RewriteRule ^buy?Type=([A-Za-z]+)&Step=([A-Za-z]+)&Id=([A-Za-z]+)$ buy/$1/$2/$3 [L,QSA]
```

Can you help me?

EDIT: If it helps, I write here the part of the RewriteRule of my .htaccess file.

```
## Mod_rewrite in use.    
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php    
## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.    
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
#RewriteRule ^cgm/?(.*) /$1 [R=301,L]
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
#RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects
##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
# RewriteBase /
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} buy?Type=([^=&]+)&Step=([^=&]+)&Id=([^=&]+)$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ buy/%1/%2/%3? [L,QSA]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: @stribizhev it isn't work. I'm not sure that is the meaning of [^=&]+

Comment: Are you using a custom joomla component?

Comment: Yes, it´s one module that I create

Comment: Can you provide more information? Your module is outputting links to another Joomla component? /buy/event/place/1245 links to what exactly? How are you generating the links on your module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /buy\?Type=([^&]+)&Step=([^\&]+)&ID=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ buy/%1/%2/%3? [NE,NC,L,R=302] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^buy/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ buy?type=$1&step=$2&id=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Comment: It's work but it is redirect to my 404 page. Maybe is it problem of my Joomla? This new url not exist, I mean, I only want a better rewrite of my parameters and a more friendly url.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I create a module, not a component and I haven´t got any router.php file. 
But I don´t know if I can create it in a module

Answer (score 0):

If the URL you are trying to change are linked to a Joomla component, .htaccess rules will never work. The only way out is that:

- the component has a router.php file to change the URL
- you use the method `JRoute::_($url)` in your module so URLs will be automatically rewritten by the routing system